# OpenDJ - Intercepting LDAP Events

Tags: java, ldap, opends

I use OpenDJ as the authentication module of a Glassfish server that hosts some EJB 3.1 beans.
I currently use OpenDJ LDAP SDK in order to programmatically add or modify users, and I need my service to be informed of *every* LDAP event.

How can I respond to LDAP events programmatically? (e.g., a user was added or removed, a user was added or removed from a certain group / organizational unit)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to get notifications of all updated entries (or only a filtered set of entries) using LDAP Persistent Search control which is supported by both OpenDJ and the LDAP SDK.

Kind regards,

Ludo